# How to create a C# makefile in Visual Studio for Mono support?

Tags: c#, makefile

I need create makefile for my C# project. Solution contains two projects (class library and tests). I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Is there any tool for creating makefile?
Or can I create makefile manually?

Project need to be compiled in Mono and project also need makefile for GNU make.

Answer (score 1):

It depends which Build System you want to use. Actually you already have your make file.. it's the `.sln` and the `.csproj` Files. You can make it by calling `msbuild.exe YourSolution.sln` or `msbuild.exe YourProjectFile.csproj`. In Visual Studio you can right click then Project File, Unload it and edit it to extend the build process.

Comment: Sorry, I forget. Project need to be compiled in Mono and project also has makefile for GNU make.